# cómo puedo realizar la configuración para que en la dirección no sea necesario el /public

Tags: laravel, iis

Tengo una aplicación web en PHP versión 8.2.4 y Laravel Framework 10.5.1 el sitio está sobre Internet Information Service (IIS) versión 10 el servidor donde está tiene como sistema operativo Windows Server 2019, la aplicación está corriendo sobre el puerto 8089, si ingreso
la dirección `http://localhost:8089/public/` accede correctamente, como imagen adjunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiero es como puedo ingresar digitando solo el  `http://localhost:8089`

Comment: Podrías hacer que la raíz del sitio apunte directamente a la carpeta public, no?

Comment: Podrias compartir tu archivo web.confg? De esta forma podremos ayudarte y no dar palos de ciego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar el `.htaccess` dentro de public

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hay gente que recomienda sacar las cosas de la carpeta public, pero eso **NO DEBE REALIZARSE** es una mala práctica y elimina la seguridad de la aplicación. Por ejemplo tu .env sería visible por cualquiera

Como .htaccess es una directiva de apache en IIS el símil sería web.config quedando de la siguiente manera (dejo una forma de convertir el htaccess a web config, [link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365508/convert-htaccess-to-web-config).

> To convert rules from .htaccess to web.config you can use import
> feature of the IIS URL Rewrite Module:
>
> 1. Go to IIS Manager
> 2. Click you site in the tree
> 3. double-click URL Rewrite in the Feature View
> 4. click Import Rules in the Actions panel
> 5. paste your .htaccess rules into the Rewrite rules textbox and
> 6. you'd see your converted rules below.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
        <match url="^(.*)$"  />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="//public/{R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: No sabía que IIS tenía soporte para `.htaccess`, ¿estás seguro de esto?

Comment: No ISS no soporta .htaccess (esto es solo de apache, y yo solo saba una idea de por donde ir). De todos modos te adjunto en un edit el web.config que si que puede usar

Comment: No parecía una sugerencia, creo que está mucho mejor ahora. Un saludo y voy a eliminar estos comentarios que solo hacen ruido más tarde.